# Fréchet derivative of $x\mapsto{\rm D}A(x)\circ B(x)$ with $A:H\to H$ and $B:H\to\mathfrak L(U,H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, frechet-derivative

I guess the answer of this question is easy, but I just can't figure it out at the moment:

Let

- $U,H$ be Hilbert spaces
- $A:H\to H$ be twice continuously Fréchet differentiable
- $B:H\to\mathfrak L(U,H)$ be continuously Fréchet differentiable

Now, let $$\Phi(x):={\rm D}A(x)\circ B(x)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in H\;.$$ How can we calculate ${\rm D}\Phi$?

Comment: Do you assume B to be bounded and linear?

Comment: @m.s If that's necessary or helpful, you're free to assume that.

Comment: No, then Phi would be itself bounded and linear -- too easy. Sorry. But I think you want be to be cont. differentiable, don't you?

Comment: @m.s. Yes, of course.

Comment: @Mizar My guess is that $${\rm D}\Phi(x)y=\left({\rm D}^2A(x)y\right)B(x)+{\rm D}A(x)\left({\rm D}B(x)y\right)\;\;\;\text{for all }x,y\in H\;.\tag 1$$

Comment: Do $\mathfrak L(U, H)$ denote linear, continous maps (from U to H)? (See m.s' comment)

Comment: @Christoph Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Form your preconditions, $DA(x)$ is a linear and continous map from $H$ to $H$. Using the chain rule you otain

$$D\Phi(x)y={\rm D (DA(x)B(x)y)}\circ D(B(x)y)$$

As $DA(x)$ is linear this simplifies to

$$D\Phi(x)y=DA(x)\circ D(B(x)y)$$

If you don't know anything about $B$, that should be the result (You know that B is coniuously Frechet differentiable). If $B(x)$ is linear and continous this simplifies further and you achieve m.s' result.